# COMMAND_EXECUTION_ERROR: Error while executing command Reason: exit status 3

Tags: angular, server-side-rendering, aws-codepipeline, aws-codebuild

Its all of the sudden the my aws codepipe line build project started thorowing this error. It used to work fine before.

```
COMMAND_EXECUTION_ERROR: Error while executing command: ng build --configuration production && ng run project-name:server. Reason: exit status 3
```

[image]

My buildspec

```
version: 0.2
env:
  variables:
    APP_NAME: "projectname"
    CACHE_CONTORL : "86400"
    S3_BUCKET: "https://s3.amazonaws.com/test1.project.com/"
    BUILD_FOLDER: "projectname-ng/dist"
phases:
  install:
    runtime-versions:
      nodejs: 14.x
    commands:
      - echo install process started
      - npm install -g @angular/cli
      - cd project-name-ng
      - npm install
  build:
    commands:
      - echo build process started now
      - ng build --configuration production && ng run project-name:server
      - echo Archiving to deployment.zip
      - node archive.js
  post_build:
    commands:
      - echo build process finished, we should uplload to S3 now

artifacts:
    files:
      - '**/*'
    base-directory: 'projectname-ng/dist'
```

My runtime environment.

[image]

While checking logs I found node 14.19 is installed but min 14.20 is needed.

```
2022-11-18T14:57:33.532+05:30   Node.js version v14.19.2 detected.

The Angular CLI requires a minimum Node.js version of either v14.20, v16.13 or v18.10.
```

While I manually change it to 14.20 it says this error.

```
YAML_FILE_ERROR Message: Unknown runtime version named '14.20' of nodejs.
```

Again this is all of the sudden. It was working before today.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe today latest version of Angular 15 was introduce and installing the global version of angular was installing 15. Maybe that is causing the issue. I am completely not sure.

But I have manage to fixed it by mentioning version `16.x` on buildspec and build image to `aws/codebuild/standard:6.0`. After that I release the current change from pipeline. It was fixed. Build successfull. If you see error during `npm install` then try delete package.lock.json and run again.

As per the [aws codebuild user guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/available-runtimes.html) if using node version 16.x then we have to use build image 6.0.

Hope it helps.